# Ambiguous reference exception in ASP.NET usercontrols

Tags: asp.net, iis, namespaces, web-config

Is there a way to prevent an ASCX control to use namespaces included in the web config `system.web/pages/namespaces`, which will lead to a ambiguous reference exception.

The smallest example I can think of, to reproduce the behavior:

a) MyAssembly with following class:

```cs
namespace MyAssembly.Namespace
{
  public class Constants
  {
    public const string MyConstant = "Hello World";
  }
}
```

b) An ASCX UserControl with following content:

```xml
<%@ Control Language="C#" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                   PublicKeyToken=0123456789abcdef" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyAssembly.Namespace" %>
<%: Constants.MyConstant %>
```

c) Following modification in the web.config file:

```xml
system.web/compilation/assemblies:
  <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.PWA, Version=15.0.0.0,
                 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
system.web/pages/namespaces:
  <add namespace="Microsoft.Office.Project.PWA" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to specify a namespace alias as a workaround:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="myAlias=System.MyNamespace" %>
```

And then use the alias throughout your .ascx file like:

```
<myAlias:MyControl />
```

Comment: Nice Idea, I haven't thought of! However, I would prefer a more generic solution maybe using an attribute of the control or similar. Consider a solution with hundreds of user controls and plenty of referenced assemblies - it's therefore a really dumb job, to replace all the Imports; not to mention the usages within the code ...

Comment: Hmm...you could try deploying a separate web.config file to the folder which your user controls reside in and make sure that all namespace imports inherited from the parent web.config files are cleared:

<system.web>
  <pages>
    <namespaces>
      <clear />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web>

See [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides) for details.